# App stuck while downloading at stage of 2%

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore, reboot

I have downloaded two apps using iPhone App Store in the morning and they were downloaded successfully. My apps stuck when I was trying to download 1 of the app called Ninjump. It's still showing in downloading mode but no progress has been made yet.

Rebooting doesn't resolved my problem too. Its still in downloading mode. I have full Internet Speed right now. I can browse as well so there is no chance app is stuck due to Internet.

How can I remove that app which is still in downloading mode?

Comment: You _might_ want to give it some time, what with the recent announcements at WWDC, the app-store may be a little glitchy. See how it fares tomorrow. Also, have you done a full reboot (holding down LOCK until you get the "swipe to turn off" message)? Just checking; a reboot nearly always clears these things up for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap the Ninjump app icon once so as to pause the download. Turn on Airplane Mode in the settings. Immediately hard reset the iPhone (Sleep/Wake (Power) + Home button held simultaneously until the Apple logo is seen). Once the iPhone restarts, disable Airplane mode, allow it to connect to Wi-Fi. Usually this will have removed the app by now.

If unsuccessful, the next step will be to sign out of your Apple ID in Settings or the bottom of 'Featured' in the App Store, and repeat the process above.

Failing those two, the process can be repeated while incorporating signing into a different Apple ID to get it unstuck...and lastly a restore in rare cases.

Comment: I have tried all the steps by signout process as well... but that APP is totally idle no changes in that.. still in downloading mode with 0% status... its just a brand new white iphone.... do u want me to reset that ? How can i do that ? or is there any other way to remove that particular app only ?

Comment: If you've followed all the steps I listed and it persists, the end recommendation was, again, to hard reset the unit, or restore. Please see Apple's Troubleshooting Assistant: http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/assistant/phone/

Comment: I dont know what happen.. when i plugged my iphone with macbook... my problems got resolved... apps has been downloaded automatically. Thanks :)