# App download stuck in iOS

Tags: ios, applications

Whenever I try to download an app in iOS, the icon goes onto my Home screen, but then it gets stuck on loading.

[image: Image of loading screen here]

What do I do to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you make sure you have enough storage space available on your iOS device. Go to Settings app → General → iPhone (or iPad) Storage and check the storage space usage.

Comment: I have 2.5 gb spare

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’ve exhausted the usual steps:

- [iOS App stuck in 'Loading...'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188933/ios-app-stuck-in-loading)

Then you could either contact Apple support to check on their services and your account or make a backup of your phone - erase all content and seettings and see if things are better after a restore.

Worst case, you’d have corruption on the OS level and need to restore the OS, but usually you can remedy this by taking lighter handed steps as opposed to wiping the system or the data of all apps being loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Settings -General -in about Available data -data usage

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on what you're saying or perhaps even add a screenshot? Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.