# Deleting an App that refuses to go away

Tags: applications, macos

I have been trying to delete the United Airlines app from my iPad because I won't be needing it anytime soon.  I thought I had successfully deleted it but a gray version keeps reappearing.  I've deleted the gray version several times with no success.

What can I do to delete it permanently?

Answer (score 2):

I usually do the same thing [when installing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/iphone-apps-in-waiting-mode-for-the-last-4-days) or [deleting stalls](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22575/how-can-i-remove-this-half-downloaded-app-from-my-iphone), put the device in airplane mode, turn off WiFi, turn off Bluetooth and power it down.

When it starts, delete the app, then enable communications as desired.

When that fails, it’s easy to collect diagnostic information and send to Apple, but usually it’s a stuck network or storage issue that starting with a clean OS start in trolls whatever process was jammed.